# Registering multiple handlers while running server

Tags: clojure, ring, compojure, http-kit

Is there any way to register multiple handlers while running an http-kit server:

```
(defroutes rest-main-app
  (GET "/" "Welcome"))

(defroutes rest-events-app
  (GET "/events" "Event API"))

(defn -main []
  (run-server rest-main-app {:port 5000}))
```

How can I pass both routes to the run-server e.g both  rest-main-app and rest-events-app ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use compojure's [`routes`](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/blob/639fffd3f8b77153644d0c9b87bca5af56be0cb0/src/compojure/core.clj#L129) function. You can also pass several handlers to `defroutes`, an example is provided below:

```
(defroutes get-routes
  (GET "/events" [] "Event API")
  (GET "/" [] "Welcome"))

(defroutes post-routes
  (POST "/events" [] "Post Event API"))

(def all-routes 
  (routes
   get-routes
   post-routes))

(defn -main []
  (run-server all-routes {:port 5000}))
```